# Overwrite previously exported Excel file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, table

I am exporting a table to Excel and I would like the overwrite access to be on. Below is the code line. Please let me know how I can give overwrite access through the code if it is possible.

```
#Export to Excel
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion("UniqueTandR",toolpath+"/FinalResult.xls","ALIAS","DESCRIPTION")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your code, above your line where you export the table.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion("UniqueTandR",toolpath+"/FinalResult.xls","ALIAS","DESCRIPTION")
```

Comment: I set this true before. Do I have to set it true every line I have a variable I want to be overwritten?

Comment: Spinel's answer is correct. The default value for `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` is `False`.  Whenever a gp tool/function is run, first it checks if the output exists, if yes and `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` is `True` the output data is deleted, then operation proceeds.  If  `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` is `False`, the operation fails.